# Why is querying a document cheaper than loading it by id?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I can get a specific document from CosmosDB by fetching it by id (for example, using cosmosDB .NET API     `client.ReadDocumentAsync(documentLink)`) or by selecting it using sql-like syntax ( `select * from c where c.id='key'`) over any indexed key.

I played with different file sizes to load **the same full document** using both methods (using C#, client Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB, v2.9.1) using real world sample documents and got the following RU costs:

```
Document size    Read       Select
1KB              1,00 RU    2,89 RU
6KB              1,33 RU    3,02 RU
100KB            9,95 RU    5,82 RU
200KB           20,29 RU    8,65 RU
```

Note that RU costs are significantly different. It can get notable on your bill.

By this test, it seems it is preferable to use `ReadDocument` API for small documents. Ok, that's a common suggestion.

The second takeaway is to use `select` for "larger" documents.. and this seems counter intuitive and makes me paranoid. The [Request Units in Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/request-units) page is rather vague about if this could be  intentional.

**Are there some side-effects I'm not taking into account here? Or is the RU cost function just not reflecting the (presumably almost equal) real operation cost too well?**

**EDIT:** 
Select RU usage is taken from `query.ExecuteNextAsync()` response object (which is executed once and I do read the expected 1 document content). Also, I get identical RU usage when executing the same query in MS Azure Storage Explorer. I surely hope there are no hidden costs here.

Comment: For the query did you actually read the data by doing a while-loop on resultSetIterator.HasMoreResults? and draining the iterator or are you just counting RU for container.GetItemQueryIterator()?

Comment: I'm using the older API version (which should not affect RU usage), added select RU origin details to Q.

Comment: Investigating this now. Will revert with more details ASAP. Thanks.