# How to download many separate JSON documents from CosmosDB without deserializing?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

#### Context & goal

I need to periodically create snapshots of cosmosDB partitions. That is:

1. export all documents from a single CosmosDB partition. Ca 100-10k doc per partition, 1KB-200KB each doc, entire partition JSON usually <50M)
2. each document must be handled separately, with `id` known.
3. Host the process in Azure function app, using consumption plan (so mem/CPU/duration matters).

And run this for thousands of partitions..

Using `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos` v3 C# API.

#### What I've tried

I can skip deserialization using the `Container.*StreamAsync()` tools in API, and avoid parsing the document contents. This should notably reduce the CPU/Mem need also avoids accidentally touching the documents to be exported with serialization roundtrip. The tricky part is how to combine it with having 10k documents per partition.

##### Query individually x 10k

I could query item ids per partition using SQL and just send send separate `ReadItemStreamAsync(id)` requests.

This skips deserialization, still have ids, I could control how many docs are in memory at given time, etc.

It would work, but it smells as too chatty, sending 1+10k requests to CosmosDB per partition, which is a lot = millions of requests.. Also, by my experience [SQL-querying large documents would usually be RU-wise cheaper than loading those documents by point reads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59899657/why-is-querying-a-document-cheaper-than-loading-it-by-id) which would add up in this scale. It would be nice to be able to pull N docuents with a single (SQL query) request..

##### Query all as stream x 1.

There is `Container.GetItemQueryStreamIterator()` for which I could just pass in `select * from c where c.partiton = @key`. It would be simpler, use less RUs, I could control batch size with `MaxItemsCount`, it sends just a minimal number or requests to cosmos (query+continuations). All is good, except ..

.. it would return a **single JSON array for all documents in batch** and I would need to deserialize it all to split it into individual documents and mapping to their ids. Defeating the purpose of loading them as `Stream`.

Similarly, `ReadManyItemsStreamAsync(..)` would return the items as **single** response stream.

### Question

**Does the CosmosDB API provide a better way to download a lot of individual raw JSON documents without deserializing?**
Preferably with having some control over how much data is being buffered in client.

Comment: You mentioned that ReadItem is a possibility, does that mean you already know all the ids you expect to read?

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta I don't have the ids in client, but 1 small lookup select per partition seems cheap enough.

Answer (score 1):

While I agree that designing the solution around streaming documents with change feed is promising and might have better scalability and cost-effect on cosmosDB side, but to answer the original question ..

**The chattiness of solution "*Query individually x 10k*" could be reduced [with Bulk mode](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/introducing-bulk-support-in-the-net-sdk/).**

That is:

1. Prepare a bulk `CosmosClient` with [`AllowBulkExecution` option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.cosmosclientoptions.allowbulkexecution?view=azure-dotnet)
2. query document ids to export (`select c.id from c where c.partition = @key`)
3. (Optionally) split the ids to batches of desired size to limit the number of documents loaded in memory.
4. For each batch:

   1. Load all documents in batch concurrently using `ReadItemStreamAsync(id, partition)`, this avoids deserialization but retains link to `id`.
   2. Write all documents to destination before starting next batch to release memory.

**Since all reads are to the same partition, then bulk mode will internally merge the underlying requests to CosmosDB**, reducing the network "chattiness" and trading this for some internal (hidden) complexity and slight increase in latency.

It's worth noting that:

- It is still doing the 1+10k queries to cosmosDB + their RU cost. It's just compacted in network.
- batching ids and waiting on batch completion is required as otherwise Bulk would send all internal batches concurrently (See: [Bulk support improvements for Azure Cosmos DB .NET SDK](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/bulk-improvements-net-sdk/)). Or don't, if you prefer to max out throughput instead and don't care about memory footprint. In this case the partitions are smallish enough so it does not matter much.
- Bulk has a separate internal batch size. Most likely its best to use the same value. This seems to be 100, which is a rather good chunk of data to process anyway.
- Bulk may add latency to requests if waiting for internal batch to fill up
  before dispatching (100ms). Imho this is largely neglible in this case and could be avoided by fully filling the internal Bulk batch bucket if possible.

This solution is not optimal, for example due to burst load put on CosmosDB, but the **main benefit is simplicity of implementation, and the logic could be run in any host, on-demand, with no infra setup required.**.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything out of the box that provides a means to doing on-demand, per-partition batch copying of data from Cosmos to blob storage.

However, before looking at other ways you can do this as a batch job, another approach you may consider, is to stream your data using Change Feed from Cosmos to blob storage. The reason is that, for a database like Cosmos, throughput (and cost) is measured on a per-second basis. The more you can amortize the cost of some set of operations over time, the less expensive it is. One other major thing I should point out too is, the fact that you want to do this on a per-partition basis means that the amount of throughput and cost required for the batch operation will be a combination of throughput * the number of physical partitions for your container. This is because when you increase throughput in a container, the throughput is allocated evenly across all physical partitions, so if I need 10k RU additional throughput to do some work on data in one container with 10 physical partitions, I will need to provision 100k RU/s to do the same work for the same amount of time.

Streaming data is often a less expensive solution when the amount of data involved is significant. Streaming effectively amortizes cost over time reducing the amount of throughput required to move that data elsewhere. In scenarios where the data is being moved to blob storage, often when you need the data is not important because blob storage is very cheap (0.01 USD/GB)
compared to Cosmos (0.25c USD/GB)

As an example, if I have 1M (1Kb) documents in a container with 10 physical partitions and I need to copy from one container to another, the amount of RU needed to do the entire thing will be 1M RU to read each document, then approximately 10 RU (with no indexes) to write it into another container.

Here is the breakdown for how much incremental throughput I would need and the cost for that throughput (in USD), if I ran this as a batch job over that period of time. Keep in mind that Cosmos DB charges you for the maximum throughput per hour.

- Complete in 1 second = 11M RU/s $880 USD * 10 partitions = $8800 USD
- Complete in 1 minute = 183K RU/s $14 USD * 10 partitions = $140 USD
- Complete in 10 minutes = 18.3K $1/USD * 10 partitions = $10 USD

However, if I streamed this job over the course of a month, the incremental throughput required would be, only 4 RU/s which can be done without any additional RU at all. Another benefit is that it is usually less complex to stream data than to handle as a batch. Handling exceptions and dead-letter queuing are easier to manage. Although because you are streaming, you will need to first look up the document in blob storage and then replace it due to the data being streamed over time.

There are two simple ways you can stream data from Cosmos DB to blob storage. The easiest is Azure Data Factory. However, it doesn't really give you the ability to capture costs on a per logical partition basis as you're looking to do.

To do this you'd need to write your own utility using change feed processor. Then within the utility, as you read in and write each item, you can capture the amount of throughput to read the data (usually 1 RU/s) and can calculate the cost of writing it to blob storage based upon the per unit cost for whatever your monthly hosting cost is for the Azure Function that hosts the process.

As I prefaced, this is only a suggestion. But given the amount of data and the fact that it is on a per-partition basis, may be worth exploring.

Comment: It's tricky to reliably capture deletes when building on change feeds. Good point about the cost of a batch vs streaming solution, though.  Designing around the latter is definitely more scalable on CosmosDB side, but it adds more complexity and costs to processing side. Balancing act ;)